# Is it possible to manipulate Drive Picker DOM?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing a hybrid mobile app using the Drive Picker API, which I open in an in-app browser. I need to add some events and scripts to that picker. Is the HTML structure constant, or can it change at any time?

Answer (score 0):

it  can change anytime. its not an api, its a user interface and is likely already constantly changing. use the api instead which does have guarantees of not changing without notice.

Comment: Hi @Zig Mandel , the problem is that when i use the api i get this error: Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
and using the api in an hybrid app the origine is [file://] and this is not allowed and i got this error 
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('file://')

Comment: so i tried to open the picker in an inappbrowser but the problem is that i need to inject the function to retrieve the document id of the selected document.

Comment: how do you inject code in inappbrowser? does the doc id show maybe in the url? you can watch url changes in inappbrowser

Comment: No it is not showing, and since i am not using the api , i can't pass a call back function to be executed after clicking the select button ,So i injected the code(listner) with the function executeScript() and i am retrieving the doc id from the dom ( the "data-id" attribute ).

Comment: are you using cordova? another way is to open inappbrowser to a webpage of yours which sets the id in the url. that works

Comment: yes i am using Cordova. i didn't understand exactly what you mean ,but what i need is to get the id of the selected doc on the picker. and actually i am opening the drive picker url [https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol] in the inappbrowser and i am passing the access Token on the path params (i used a cordova plugin for authentication wich return the access token).

Comment: You could instead open a url for your server which displays the picker as popup and modifies the url to include the id.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. "X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN" and " Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'". I was looking at the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) about supporting older browsers and using the `setRelayUrl` method. But I'm using Firebase as the backend for my ionic app. Did you find a solution? Can you post a code example? Thanks.